# Saving/Exporting the results of a Spark SQL Zeppelin query

Tags: apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

We're using apache zeppelin to analyse our datasets.  We have some queries that we would like to run that have a large number of results that come back from them and would like to run the query in zeppelin but save the results (display is limited to 1000).  Is there an easy way to get zeppelin save all the results of a query to s3 bucket maybe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to whip up a notebook that effectively does what i want using the scala interpreter.

```
z.load("com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0")
val df= sqlContext.sql("""
select * from table
""")

df.repartition(1).write
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .save("s3://amazon.bucket.com/csv_output/")
```

Its worth mentioning that the z.load function seemed to work for me one day, but then i tried it again and for some reason i had to declare it in its own paragraph with the %dep interpreter, then the remaining code in the standard scala interpreter

Comment: Thanks!  FWIW in my context I did not need to load the databricks module at all.